# Regular expression using positive lookbehind not working in Alteryx

Tags: regex, alteryx

I am trying to match a string the 2nd word after "Vores ref.:"  using positive lookbehind. It works in online testers like https://regexr.com/, but my tool Alteryx dont allow quantifiers like + in a lookbehind.

"ABC This is an example Vores ref.: 23244-2234 **LW782837673** Test 2324324"

`(?<=Vores\sref.:\s\d+-\d+\s+)\w+`  is correctly matching the LW78283767, on regexr.com but not in Alteryx.

How can I rewrite the lookahead expression by using quantifiers but still get what I want?

Comment: You can use a capture group instead `\bVores\sref\.:\s\d+-\d+\s+(\w+)` https://regex101.com/r/NQZizZ/1

Comment: Did the solutions below help you solve the issue? Please consider accepting the one that worked best for you, or please drop a comment if you still need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a replacement approach here using

```js
.*?\bVores\s+ref\.:\s+\d+-\d+\s+(\w+).*
```

Replace with `$1`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NBBSZp/3).

*Details*:

- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\bVores` - whole word `Vores`
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `ref\.:` - `ref.:` substring
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `\d+-\d+` - one or more digits, `-` and one or more digits
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(\w+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more word chars.
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason in Alteryx it snap the whole line from Vores. maybe the \K dont works i Alteryx implementation.

Comment: @AndreasHjortbergMeyer I changed to a replacing approach, this will work.

Comment: @AndreasHjortbergMeyer See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NBBSZp/4) that should solve your additional problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a capture group instead.

Note to escape the dot `\.` to match it literally.

```
\bVores\sref\.:\s\d+-\d+\s+(\w+)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bVores\sref\.:\s\d+-\d+\s+` Your pattern turned into a match
- `(\w+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ word characters

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NQZizZ/1)

Comment: Perfect it works in Alteryx, although it create two groups. But I just delete the first group.

Comment: @AndreasHjortbergMeyer Ok, did that solve the initial question?